# Is it possible to read data from a MSSQL database using Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been trying to connect to Azure Database using Apache Beam and hopefully use pandas to load some data inside of dataframes. To achieve this I've been using apache_beam.io.jdbc module .

I couldn't find any real documentation on the subject besides the:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.43.0/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        result = (p
                  | 'Read from jdbc' >> ReadFromJdbc(
                    fetch_size=None,
                    table_name='table_name',
                    driver_class_name='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
                    jdbc_url='jdbc:sqlserver://xxx:1433',
                    username='xxx',
                    password='xxx',
                    query='SELECT * from table_name',
                    connection_properties = ';database=xxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;'
                  )
                  |beam.Map(print)
                  )
```

I am aware that there are easier ways of doing this, but I need this way in order to ingest data to GoogleCloud BigQuery using DataFlow.

Is Apache Beam even intended to load data from a database?

Comment: Yes, Beam can be used to load data from a database to another.
Beam is interesting if you transformations to apply and also for high volume.

Comment: You link target on a very old Beam version. The actual version is : `2.43.0`

Comment: I didn't really understood what is your problem ?

Comment: I changed the link in the question to target on latest version

Comment: Is there any concrete documentation/guide on how to accomplish this? My main question and interest is creating a pipeline from an Azure SQL Database to Google BigQuery(basically replicate tables), but I cannot find any documentation on how to actually do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply this logic on `Beam` and load from `MSSQL` database to `BigQuery`, you can do that with pure `Beam` code instead of using dataframe :

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        (
            p | 'Read from jdbc' >> ReadFromJdbc(
                table_name='jdbc_external_test_read',
                driver_class_name='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
                jdbc_url='jdbc:sqlserver://xxx:1433',
                username='postgres',
                password='postgres',
                classpath=['com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:11.2.2.jre8'])
              | "Your transformation before BQ if neeeded" >> beam.Map(your_transform)
              | "write_hist_intraday" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                project="project_id",
                dataset="dataset",
                table="table",
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                
        )

def your_transform(element):
  # apply your transformation logic
```

- With `ReadFromJdbc` read your data from `MQSQL` database (check the details to access to external database)
- Then possibly apply a transformation with `Map` before to write the data to `BigQuery`
- Write the result to `BigQuery` with `WriteToBigQuery` IO. The result should be a Python `Dict` that matches the schema of the `BigQuery` table.

Comment: Pipeline fails with : 
NameError: name 'pipeline_options' is not defined

Comment: I edited my code.
My code shows an example, you have then to adapt it to work correctly in your case.

Comment: I've added connection_properties and classpath to ReadFromJdbc, but I cant seem to read the jar driver i've put on the google storage... Any ideas why? 
classpath='gs://driversjdbc/sqljdbc_11.2.1.0_enu/enu/mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre11.jar'

Without that classpath I get :
RuntimeError: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.BeamSchemaInferenceException: Failed to infer Beam schema 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: I've also tried loading the driver from inside the shell :

 classpath='/home/user/sqljdbc_11.2.1.0_enu_enu_mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre11.jar'

Comment: Normally it's correct to use `classpath` param of the `ReadFromJdbc` class and it should work.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example using the following driver with Gradle format `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:11.2.2.jre8`. The py doc indicates that we also can use this format. I passed a list instead of string as you used in your comment. I preferred using a version with `jre8` because `Beam` is more compatible with `jdk8`. By default `Postgres` driver is used in this class : `DEFAULT_JDBC_CLASSPATH = ['org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.16']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251107/discussion-between-diskosuperstar-and-mazlum-tosun).

Comment: Hey Mazlum, it seems that I was able to connect to the source
but when trying to push the table to BigQuery I'm getting :
ValueError: Failed to decode schema due to an issue with Field proto:
this seems to be an issue with incompatible datatypes between MSSQL and BigQuery.

Is it maybe possible to load MSSQL tables into google cloud storage as avro/parquet files?

Comment: Sorry I will continue to the chat discussion. Can you please check the output PCollection after retrieving data of MSSQL database ? To be able to write correctly data to Bigquery, you need to have a PCollection of Dict. The Dict should exactly respect the schema of the BigQuery table.