# No SQL drivers on Google Cloud Platform but my Cloud function needs to pull from a Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, driver, pyodbc

I have a 2nd gen Google Cloud function that needs to pull data from a Microsoft SQL Server. The Microsoft SQL server would appear to be remote as its hostname resembles `upload.gaap.com`. To connect to it, the following has been used successfully on my local machine:

```py
import pyodbc
import json

CREDENTIALS = 'blah_blah.json'

def establish_connector():
    with open(CREDENTIALS,'r') as file:
        credentials = json.load(file)
    connector = pyodbc.connect(
                               'DRIVER={SQL Server};'+\
                               f'SERVER={credentials["server"]};'+\
                               f'DATABASE={credentials["database"]};'+\
                               f'UID={credentials["username"]};'+\
                               f'PWD={credentials["password"]}'
                               )
    return connector
```

In order for the connector to be established a driver is required, in this case `SQL Server` was available on my local machine.

Once can find available drivers using `pyodbc.drivers()`. It does not seem like any drivers are available when using a Cloud function or something like Google Colab. What are my alternative options that involve still using the Google Cloud Platform (GCP)? Would it be possible to get a driver in an Apache Beam pipeline on Google DataFlow or can I somehow install a driver to work on Cloud functions. There is of course the Virtual Machine approach but if something more simple can work then I am open to it.

NOTE: the purpose of the cloud function is to pull data from SQL Server, process it and then load it to Big Query. Perhaps I am not using the right tools for such ETL.

Comment: Thank you for comment. It is not a local sql server. It is a SQL server from a firm's point of sales provider.

Comment: You know what TomTom, I am not you punching bag. If you are having a bad day take it somewhere else. I stated that THE DRIVER available on my local machine was SQL Server AND NOT THE ACTUAL SQL DATABASE. Drivers...have you heard of them? So either, provide constructive input or take your moods somewhere else.

Comment: Other examples of drives include `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. I used `SQL Server`. Now you have learned something @TomTom.

Comment: @DylanSolms that's an old driver (current is 18) but no matter the driver or the database server, you can't just connect to any other company's databases. At the very least you'd need a VPN connecting your network and theirs. That's no different even if their database is hosted on the same Google Cloud data center. As far as *Google* is concerned, they're on different networks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your constructive comment. It is probably very important to mention that this SQL server might be remote as its hostname is something like `upload.gaap.com`. In light of such new information, might it be possible to still connect to it via a Cloud function?

Comment: The `{SQL Server}` driver is the old, unsupported and no longer shipped, SQL Server Native Client driver that stopped getting updates with SQL Server 2012 - and doesn't exist for non-Windows platforms. You might have to do a bit of spelunking to figure out what's available to you on the system, the Google Cloud Functions [runtimes for Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#functions-concepts-scopes-python) are based on an Ubuntu 18.04 or 22.04 image. i.e.: if FreeTDS is installed then you could use the `pymssql` module instead of `pyodbc`.

Comment: If the SQL Server is remote I suspect connecting with TDS is a bad idea. Is it possible to write a RESTAPI and install it at the same location as the SQL Server?

Comment: @Aardvark The remote SQL server is not on our premises. It belongs to our point-of-sales service provider. We only have credentials to establish a connection to it via a suitable connector such as `pyodbc`. It seems that Google Cloud DataFlow allows for a Python SDK Apache Beam pipeline to be written that makes use of the `beam-nuggets` library that uses a Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) connector. This seems like a potentially hassle-free solution. The reason I did not start with Cloud DataFlow is because of its long start up times / latency. The scheduled VM still seem like an option.

Comment: I think this might be a Cloud DataFlow solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098809/is-it-possible-to-read-data-from-a-mssql-database-using-apache-beam.